# script to save a .py into another directory within the file itself

Tags: python, save

Let's say I create a file called file.py in a directory called directory1. When running file.py, is there a way I can have file.py save it's own script to another directory, say directory2, as a .txt file or a .py file?

Thank you!

Comment: You _could_... but why would you?

Comment: What did you try so far (i.e. any code example)?

Comment: @RyanJ: because I change parameters every time I run the file and need to keep track of what I am doing. Instead of saving them 1 by 1, it's much more convenient to save the script.

Comment: @Marcin : I have no idea whatsoever how to go about this.

Comment: This can be important when carrying out experiments @RyanJ Also I saw different version control tools being suggested below. Those do have their merits but I think sometimes a simple solution like this works best for scientific experiments. If anyone has other suggestions for this kind of scenario it would be great to hear about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generelly, if you're using an editor to write the code, you could just save it to another directory with different file extension.
But do I guess right that you want to get a backup in a different direcotry? It depends on your editor, most will do that nowadays.

But sure you can write something like this in your file which just copies it to a dir of your choice:

```
import os, shutil

if not os.access(dirname, os.F_OK):
    os.mkdir(dirname, 0o700)

shutil.copy(fname, dirname)
```

What this code does is, it first creates a directory if it doesn't exist, jet, and gives it read, write and execute permissions. Than it copies the content of fname, which contains the file name of the file itself and copies it to the directory you just created.

But why woul you copy the recent code you just wrote to a different location?

Edit:

For keeping track of your work, there are better ways to do that, for example version control systems like darcs, subversion (aka svn) or gitorious (which is mainly webbased). They save your work with different version numbers and you don't have to alter the file names each time you achieved a milestone. They help you opening up branches, join them later and keep your code executable if you choose to get an earlier version.

With:

```
fname = "work_today.txt"
```

you can save the code, even the very same code of the file it contains, to new file name.
you have to alter the filename correctly, cut off the extension and concatenate the new string. –

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have good reasons to save it to another directory, one being that I can save it with a different name, for example fname_todaysdate, as well as other output files. By the way, would you know how to save it as a .txt?

Comment: For keeping track of your work I recommend a version control system like darcs, subversion or gitorious. I saves your work with different version numbers and you do not have to alter the file names each time to achieved a milestone

Comment: yes, you can just alter the fname to fname = "work_today.txt" but using a version control system is much more comfortable and keeps your code executable at once. You can open up branches, re-join them and take a look at the differences of to versions easyly.

Comment: I have no doubt that those tools must be very useful, however in my  particular situation my options are pretty much limited to what I can write in a .py file.

Comment: let's take subversion (svn) as an example: you can just add a file by saying svn add blub.py and if you what to save a change just say svn commit  and it saves a new version. Those tools were made easy to make things easier

Comment: you have to alter the filename correctly, cut off the extension and concatenate the new string.

Comment: Then ask @camaro to edit his answer to add the comments, then *accept* that answer.  That's how StackOverflow works!

Comment: done. added the important infos of the comments to the answer.

Comment: @camaro Is there any particular reason one would use [`os.access()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access) instead of [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)?

Comment: `os.access()` tests wether the target exists and can be accessed, so asking if one has the permission to do so, too. What good is just knowing that it exists if you run into the problem of being unable to access it the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this function in your ".py" file and then use it in the same file.

```
import os, shutil
def save_this_file(output_path):
    """
    Copy the current .py file to another directory as a backup
    output_path: full path of a folder
    """
    path_this_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)  # full path of the current .py file
    base_name = os.path.basename(path_this_file)  # 'abc.py'
    dst = os.path.join(output_path, base_name)  # construct the full path of destination
    shutil.copy(src=path_this_file, dst=dst)  # copy this file to destination
```

Notice that:

1. output_path is the full path of the destination folder;
2. the copied ".py" file keeps the same name as the original file;
3. if you import this function to another ".py" file, it will save the file in which it is located.