# Python- save a copy of the current script with the date/time added to the name

Tags: python

I have a python script `script1.py` which will be run from differing various directories.

I'd like to add some code so that when this script is finished, it will save a copy of itself in a separate absolute directory (say, `/mnt/scratch/logs` ), and also save the copy with the date and time at the end of the name string, e.g.

```
/mnt/scratch/logs/script1_2017_nov_10.py
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt something like this to your needs

```
import datetime as dt
import re

filename = 'script'
timestamp = str(dt.datetime.now())[:19]
timestamp = re.sub(r'[\:-]','', timestamp) # replace unwanted chars 
timestamp = re.sub(r'[\s]','_', timestamp) # with regex and re.sub

print('{}_{}'.format(filename,timestamp))
```

will output

```
script_20171109_224530
```

adding these lines and a bit of ingenuity will make the rest, but go with Prune advice for your next questions :)

```
# not included in output file
out_filename = ('{}_{}'.format(filename,timestamp))

with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as out:
        for line in (f.readlines()[:-7]): #remove last 7 lines
            print(line, end='', file=out)
```

Comment: Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27808771/11542679) from another post for the file saving part especially if you want to create a new directory for the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime` package.  Fetch the current date in your desired format.  Use string operations to alter the punctuation.  Append that to the string "/mnt/scratch/logs/script1_", and there's your file name.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go using 'from datetime import date /n savelog = '/mnt/scratch/logs/script1_{}.py'.format(date.today()) /n f = open(savelog, 'w'). I'm a bit of a noob though- that only creates a new empty file. How would I copy all the text in the current script1 over to that?

Comment: You look up how to write data to a file.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: No problem.  That's not anger; more of "Sorry, bro, that's the end of our leash."  When the question gets to coding basic skills that are in many tutorials, we expect you to find it on your own -- and probably learn the next five things while you're looking.